# How can I edit the link's text before it opens upon click?

Tags: google-chrome

How can I edit the link's text before it opens upon click?

For example, suppose I click on a link that will open the following link:

```
www.banana.tr\www.google.com
```

I want to know if there is an extension that notices the `www.banana.tr`, delete it and opens only `www.google.com`. What I'm looking for is closely related with ad.ly blockers, but I want one of those that allow me to edit the string that is being removed.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking for.  I'm not familiar with ad.ly blockers, so that reference isn't helpful, especially when you add that you want something different.  In the comment on the answer, you say you want something to do it for you, but you want to edit the string (seems contradictory).  Is it just a specific string you want to specify and screen?  Your title and question do not do a good job of describing what you want.

Answer (score 1):

#### How can I edit the link's text before it opens upon click?

1. Right click on the link
2. Select `Copy link address`

[image]

3. Paste into the chrome address bar
4. Edit the link
5. Press <kbd>enter</kbd> to open the link

---

#### I want something to do it for me.

> I'm trying to find something similar to ad.ly blockers, but something that allows me to enter the string of text I want.

You can write a [greasemonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) or [tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/) script to achieve this.

Comment: Yes, I know I can do that. But as my question states, I want something to do it for me. I'm trying to find something similar to ad.ly blockers, but something that allows me to enter the string of text I want.

Comment: @JesusChrist See updated answer